# MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Al momento de ejecutar el siguiente código

```
void main() {
  runApp(Home());
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    print(deviceData);
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Caducidad productos',
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 247, 247, 1),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: _screen(context),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Me aparece el siguiente error

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#6f161):
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().
This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce
a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.
The context used was:
  Home
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Home
```

Por lo que he buscado sólo he encontrado que según context no contiene MediaQuery, pero no sé que otra cosa tengo que poner para que tenga el media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede usar `MediaQuery` fuera del `MaterialApp` a menos que uses el `MediaQuery` directamente como widget padre (que el MaterialApp) ya lo trae, tienes 2 formas de solucionar esto.

1- Crea un widget por debajo de `MaterialApp` y desde ahí puedes acceder a `MediaQuery`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Caducidad productos',
      home: MiNuevoWidget(),
    );
  }


class MiNuevoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 247, 247, 1),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: _screen(context),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

2- Usa el widget `Builder` para crear un contexto nuevo.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Caducidad productos',
        home: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
             var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
            print(deviceData);
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 247, 247, 1),
              body: SafeArea(
                child: _screen(context),
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
```